# Replace multiple strings with different set of mapped strings

Tags: sed, replace

I want to replace multiple string patterns with a different set of predefined strings.

For example:

Input:

```
This sentence will be converted to something different. This sentence can contain same words.
```

Output:

```
These words need to be replaced with something different. These words can contain same alphabets.
```

So here I want to convert in below pattern.

- This     =>These
- sentence =>word
- will     =>need to
- converted=>replaced
- to       => with
- words => alphabets

Let me know if it can be done.

Comment: What about `sed 's/This/These/g' input_file` or `sed 's/This/These/g' <<< input_string` respectively?

Comment: Yes, this can be done in `sed`.  It’s fairly simple, aside from the issue of cascading substitution (you want to avoid replacing “sentences” with “alphabets”). What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is in the file `data.txt` (for instance) then you could use `sed` inside a for-loop. Maybe something like this:

```
replacements=(
    This:These
    sentence:word
    will:need to
    converted:repalced
    to:with
    words:alphabets
)

for row in "${replacements[@]}"; do
    original="$(echo $row | cut -d: -f1)";
    new="$(echo $row | cut -d: -f2)";
    sed -i -e "s/${original}/${new}/g" data.txt;
done
```